# Reactjs Timezone convertion

Tags: node.js, reactjs, datetime

I am connected mssql database and get some informations includes Date_Time.

Time is coming like `2021-01-30T15:08:25.357Z`. I want to convert it to `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss` format.
So, it should be `30-01-2021 15:08:25`.

I used this method but it is not exactly that I want.

```
 var d1 = new Date(datey).toLocaleDateString("tr")
  var newTime=d1+" "+
  new Date(datey).getUTCHours()+":"+
  new Date(datey).getUTCMinutes()+":"+
  new Date(datey).getUTCSeconds()
  // it returns 30/01/2021 15:8:25
```

Maybe, In there, I want to see time fomat with 0 such as 15:08. When hour 2 a.m it just 2:0 but I want to see it 02:00.

How should I do , is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a date/time library such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), this will make date manipulation much easier, parsing and formatting your date is then very simple:

```js
const input= "2021-01-30T15:08:25.357Z";
console.log("Input date:", input);

// To convert the date to local before displaying, we can use moment().format()
const formattedDateLocal = moment(input).format("DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss");
console.log("Formatted date (Local Time):", formattedDateLocal );

// To display the UTC date, we can use moment.utc().format()
const formattedDateUTC = moment.utc(input).format("DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss");
console.log("Formatted date (UTC):", formattedDateUTC );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried moment.utc(input) with my time but on my browser output is **2021-01-30 03:08:25**. It didn't 15:08:25. Why ?  Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for testing my answer! Did you try the line: moment.utc(input).format("DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss")?;

Comment: It was what I wanted. I am thankful to you.